# STM32: Can I use xQueuePeek while using CMSIS V2?

Tags: stm32, freertos, cmsis

I'm new to STM32 and freeRTOS in general. The project I created with SMT32CubeIDE gave me the option to use freeRTOS but the choices were CMSIS V1 or V2 only. I picked V2. I've read that CMSIS Vx are wrapper for freeRTOS.

I was looking for a way to read a queue without removing the object and I found xQueuePeek. But this is freeRTOS not CMSIS Vx and CMSIS does not seem to have that function. Looking at the code for osMessageQueueGet (this is a CMSIS function) I see that it calls  xQueueReceive in "queue.h". In that same file I see xQueuePeek. I tried xQueuePeek in my main and it worked (after including "queue.h"). I'm wondering if it **is technically ok to call functions directly from  "queue.h" like xQueuePeek if there is no equivalent in CMSIS Vx?** I'm wondering if I'll break something in the future that I'm too new to know/understand. I'm not worry about portability to other MCUs or system. This is a personal project and I'm using it to learn SMT32 and freeRTOS. Thanks.